# Interrogative form confusion for sentence with is

Tags: interrogatives

I have a simple sentence:

**The dialled number format is 6762 + 2 digits.**

When I try to convert it into interrogative form, it takes this form:

**Is the dialled number format 6762 + 2 digits?**

However, this sentence does not look elegant to me. Can we have a better way to form this sentence?

Comment: Why does it not look elegant to you? It is perfectly normal English.

Comment: I think it looks inelegant simply because the phrase itself is strange.  If you consider *His name is Paul / Is his name Paul?* you will see that it is completely parallel.

Comment: I was thinking that the following is a better format: Does the dialled number format match with 6762 + 2 digits?

Comment: that would be parallel to "The dialled number format matches with 6762 + 2 digits." And I would remove the "with" from both of those sentences, if I were using them.

Comment: Or "Could you confirm that the dialled number format is 6762 + 2 digits." or "I believe the dialled number format is 6762 + 2 digits. Is that right?"